# Compare slopes for categorical data

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

Hello I want to compare the **slopes** of the linear regression lines for the following distributions of sales figures over the years 2009 to 2017. Hence I am not interested if "the blue bar is above the others" but if there is a differnce in the slope of the three categories.

[image]

I want to compare the slopes of the regression lines - examine if they differ significantly -

Approach: I draw additional confidence intervals for each regression line. If the slopes differ and the confidence intervals do not overlap for the given period, I know that the slopes are different. Is that an appropriate approach? How can I achieve it?

The data for the three categries is:

```
Blue  413 506 367 436 523 432 415 700 506 
Red     24 82 126 106 107 115 139 109 101 
Green  27   69  68  79  83  80  113 116 94
```

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fisher's z-test is a method to compare correlation coefficients. I mention this because it is possible that you have a situation where two samples have the same correlation coefficient (x is just as likely a predictor of y in both) but different slopes. And vice versa. This is important because it informs which method we use when testing the null hypothesis that the slope is the same in both samples (read more here: http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/CompareCorrCoeff.pdf)

you can find the slope for each line (here's an example for one of the lines).

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x = [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
y_blue = [944, 413, 506, 367, 436, 523, 432, 415, 700, 506]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print(slope)
```

if your sample is large ( n > 30 is what I was taught) and **you cannot assume homogeneity in variances** the z-test is simply :

```
numerator = slope1 - slope2
denominator = pow((pow(std_error1,2) + pow(std_error2,2), 1/2)
z = numerator / denominator
```

& use the z-statistic to find the p-value (read here: https://www.sophia.org/tutorials/how-to-find-a-p-value-from-a-z-test-statistic)

if you can assume homogeneity in variances, then you want to do a pooled student's t-test. Which is similar in methodology as above, just different formulas. Check the first link I posted.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I estimate if the slopes differ significantly? Is the approach with the confidence intervals appropriate?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you were asking about stats theory as well.. there are many ways to go about it.  (1) test the hypothesis that the difference between b1b1 and b2b2 (1 and 2 being two samples or times) is equal to zero you can apply the following formula: Z=b1−b2/ SEb1^2+SEb2^2 (sorry that is so messy). (2) 95 % confidence interval & check if 1 is in the interval. Read this forum, decide a method and I can help you with the code: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_how_to_test_the_significant_difference_between_a_line_slopeeg_081_and_1_by_using_R_or_SPSS

Comment: I think I nearly understand the concept but I have an additional question: 1. What do you mean by b1b1 and b2b2 and 2. You are using a z test, is it also possible to use a t test? --> For my unterstanding: A t test is normally used to compare the means of two data sets but here we simply interchange the means by the slopes of the data?

Comment: Additionally whats the concept behind the z test? Maybe you can update your answer... I think your approach is the most appropriate

Answer (score 2):

In python this can be done using [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html).
You will have to set up a single pandas dataframe with all your data in the one column (*value*), column for the year, and another column (let's call it *color_group*) which is a categorical variable indicating which group/color the data belongs in. You then set up a model a bit like this:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dat_blue = np.array([413,506,367,436,523,432,415,700,506])
dat_red = np.array([24,82,126,106,107,115,139,109,101])
dat_green = np.array([27,69,68,79,83,80,113,116,94])
values = np.r_[dat_blue, dat_red, dat_green]

yrs = np.array(range(2009,2018))
years = np.r_[yrs, yrs, yrs]

grp = np.r_[np.repeat('BLUE', 9), np.repeat('RED', 9), np.repeat('GREEN', 9)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':values, 'year':years, 'color_group':grp})

lm1 = smf.ols(formula='value ~ year * color_group', data=df).fit()
lm1.summary()
```

and then look at the results to test for the [interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)) between year and colour_group. A bit complex to go into here, but check the documentation links above. I think this will only test whether the slopes are not all the same.

Going a step further, statisticians worry about [serial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) in these sort of tests that involve time series data.

Answer (score 1):

To really estimate the statistical significance of the slopes' difference, the most methodologically accurate way would be using a two-way ANOVA. In this statistical test, the difference between the slopes refers to the INTERACTION between the main factors Sales Agent (or whatever your colors refer to) and Year. If the sales rate change differently across time for each color, then you would get an interaction between sales agent and year. 
The problem is that  there is no easy implementation of this kind of anova in python (e.g. none in scipy), that I know of. You can use the pyvttbl library, that needs to be installed.

See here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvttbl

and here https://www.marsja.se/two-way-anova-repeated-measures-using-python/

Regarding your suggestion of looking whether the confidence intervals overlap, I believe that this would not give you an accurate indication. First, the intercept (and maybe the range too?) of the 3 sales agents differ, and the confidence intervals will give you indication about the sales values, not the interaction between time and sales. Second, overlapping of confidence interval is not completely parallel to statistical significance, though many people do mix them up. You can have a statistically significance difference with overlapping error bars.

Comment: Thank you! I am not interested in the intercept. I am simply interested in the slope of the regression lines and if they are statistically significant